# turning pandas to pyspark expression

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, group-by, pyspark

I need to turn a two column Dataframe to a list grouped by one of the columns. I have done it successfully in pandas:

```
expertsDF = expertsDF.groupby('session', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

But now I am trying to do the same thing in pySpark as follows:

```
expertsDF = df.groupBy('session').agg(lambda x: x.collect())
```

and I am getting the error:

```
all exprs should be Column
```

I have tried several commands but I simply cannot get it right. And the spark dokumentation does not contain something similar.

An example input for it would be a dataframe:

```
session     name
1           a
1           b
2           v
2           c
```

output:

```
session    name
1          [a, b....]
2          [v, c....]
```

Comment: can you share example data and expected output please?

Comment: @mtoto yes sure, done!

Comment: Try this: `from pyspark.sql.functions import *; df.groupBy('session').agg(collect_list('name'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduceByKey()` to do this efficiently:

```
(df.rdd
 .map(lambda x: (x[0],[x[1]]))
 .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
 .toDF(["session", "name"]).show())
+-------+------+
|session|  name|
+-------+------+
|      1|[a, b]|
|      2|[v, c]|
+-------+------+
```

**Data**:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, "a"),
                     (1, "b"),
                     (2, "v"),
                     (2, "c")]).toDF(["session", "name"])
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list(col)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy('session').agg(collect_list('name'))
```